Neo4J: how to copy the relationships of node A to node B?
I using latest Neo4j.
and i want to copy all relationship from node id=1 to node id=2:
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE id(n) = 1
WITH r, m 
MATCH (synonym) 
WHERE id(synonym) = 2 
CREATE (synonym)-[???]->(m)

How to get the name of the relationship (r) to put in the mark ???
Thanks for help!
Updated:
i fixed it with Ashish Gupta support:
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE id(n) = 1
WITH type(r) AS relType, m 
MATCH (synonym) 
WHERE id(synonym) = 2 
CALL apoc.create.relationship(synonym, relType, {}, m) YIELD rel


I am 10mins late! I swear I did not see your update while I am testing my code/script :D

You can use an APOC function (apoc.create.relationship) for copying a relationship type to another node.
Let say, node n is Charlie Sheen and node m is Wall Street.
If node synonym is Keanu, I will create a relationship from Keanu to Wall Street using the same relationship type from Charlie to Wall Street (ACTED_IN)
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE id(n) = 1
WITH r, m 
MATCH (synonym) 
WHERE id(synonym) = 2
WITH synonym, type(r) as relationship_type, m
CALL apoc.create.relationship(synonym, relationship_type, {roles:['Neo']}, m)
YIELD rel
RETURN rel


To get the name of the relationship r to use in the CREATE clause, you can extract the relationship type dynamically using the type() function in Cypher. Here's how you can modify your query to achieve this:
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE id(n) = 1
WITH type(r) AS relType, m 
MATCH (synonym) 
WHERE id(synonym) = 2 
CREATE (synonym)-[rel:relType]->(m)
RETURN synonym, m

In this modified query:
type(r) extracts the type of the relationship r.
WITH type(r) AS relType, m stores the relationship type in the variable relType.
CREATE (synonym)-[rel:relType]->(m) creates a new relationship with the extracted relationship type relType between synonym and m.

Well, i just tried it, but it create relationship with name relType, not type(r) name
https://i.imgur.com/TaB5Im5.png

the relationship type is not able to do the evaluation of the string value of relType. Use an APOC function  apoc.create.relationship instead.

i see your answer, thanks so much.
